# How do I stretch scrollview to whole screen in react native?

Tags: react-native

I have this code

```
render() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TopMenu />
      <ScrollView style={styles.scrollView}>
        {array_with_two_items.map(this.createRow)}
      </ScrollView>
    </View>
  )
}
```

with styles

```
scrollView: {
  flex:1,
  marginBottom:0,
},
containter: {
  flex:1,
},
```

and the problem is that it looks like this

```
+-----------+
|    MENU   |
+-----------+
|   item1   |
+-----------+
|   item2   |
+-----------+
|           |
|   blank   |
|    not    |
| scrollable|
+-----------+
```

but I want it to look like

```
+-----------+
|    MENU   |
+-----------+
|   item1   |
+-----------+
|   item2   |
+-----------+
| blank,but |
|   still   |
|  part of  |
| scrollview|
+-----------+
```

I have little experience with styling and flexbox so that's why I'm asking. (Menu is not supposed to be a part of scrollview)

Comment: try to cover scrollView with <View style={{flex:1}}></View> and add a contentContainerStyle={styles.contentContainer}(it is a native prop)

Answer (score 38):

I think what you want here is `flexGrow` - [flexGrow documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flexbox#flex-basis-grow-and-shrink)

```
<ScrollView style={{ flex: 1 }} contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
  
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: thank you so much for your help this saved me days of suffering and torment

Comment: this should be the accepted answer because only flex:1 stops the scrolling of scrollview

Answer (score 13):

Just give the props **contentContainerStyle** to the ScrollView like:

```
<ScrollView
   contentContainerStyle={{
     flex: 1
  }}
>
  /* Other Stuff */
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Can you give a small code snippet of you user-case? @Yokhen

Comment: It's pretty straight forward. Use contentContainerStyle to position the ScrollView as if it was a regular View. Don't use style for positioning. Ajay's answer is pretty self explanatory. Setting flex: 1 will allow the ScrollView to take up the rest of the available space of either the Screen itself (which serves as a parent container), or the parent container your ScrollView is nested inside.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question and the other answers did not work for me. A way to do this in 2022 would be this:

```
<>
  <TopMenu />
  <ScrollView>
    {array_with_two_items.map(this.createRow)}
  </ScrollView>
</>
```

I.e. remove the outer View in favor of empty brackets, and no styling is needed in the ScrollView.

This works perfectly for me on Android and iOS and does not clip the content on the scroll (iOS) if the content does not cover the whole screen. I'm using React Native 0.68.2.